# Javascript code works perfectly on desktop & resized window but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

It's really weird. I have a `<a>` tag and whenever it is clicked it should toggle `blue-text-cat` class. It works perfectly on the desktop but doesn't work on mobile.

The weird part is when I resize the browser window and click the `<a>`, it works fine. I am saying it weird because the same page with resized browser window is shown on mobile. The code doesn't work on mobile.

```js
function toggleColorStyle(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('blue-text-cat');
}
```

```css
.blue-text-cat {
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: #000" onclick="toggleColorStyle(event)">
    JAPANESE CARS FOR SALE
</a>
```

Check this: http://pazomall.storehippo.com/ in the resized browser window and click on left menu and click on Automotive. Click "JAPANESE CARS FOR SALE"! You can see it works there but doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: Seems to be opposite for me - your mobile site changes to blue and your desktop site doesn't

Comment: @Pete did you resize the browser on desktop and checked? That way in desktop works but doesn’t work on mobile.

Comment: Yep, resized from desktop to mobile and got blue links in automotive, resized back to desktop, no blue links